# How to make content pane in Android?

Tags: android

I wanted to know how to make a content pane similar to the one shown below. I'm downloading info from an online database and want to display it nicely with a username, date, and text. How to I accomplish this? Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: use a custom listview.

Comment: How do I do this with a custom listview? Can you give me a link to where a sample is?

Comment: @ChanceLeachman why don't you google or search on so there are lots of similar posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve this by costuming a list view [follow this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).

The UI you referring is [Google's card UI](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/18/google-analytics-app-gets-a-massive-update-to-2-0-new-ui-more-data-last-site-loads-by-default-and-more/) , you my also use [this](http://nadavfima.com/cardsui-view-library/) library for similar behavior.